# how to display a div1 on hovering div2 and fading div1 on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display **div1** on hovering **div2** and disappear **div1** only if mouse is not hovering both **div1** and **div2**.

I tried using the following CSS and jquery. But the **div1** disappears immadiately after unhovering div2 and i am unable to access the content of div1.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.about').hover(
      function() {
        $('.showsection').slideDown(800).addClass('show');
      }
      , function() {
        $('.showsection').slideToggle(800);
         });
      });
```

```css
.showsection{
 display:none;
    }
    .show{
 display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=about>
  <h1>About</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="showsection">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done by attaching `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to the elements you want to show/hide.

These are the requirements:

- Show `showsection` when mouse enters `about`. This can be done using `mouseenter` on `about`
- Hide `showsection` when mouse is not hovering over both `showsection` and `about`. This  actually means checking two things: the mouse is not hovering `showsection` when it leaves `about` *and* the mouse is not hovering `about` when it leaves `showsection`. That means we have to attach `mouseleave` events to both `showsection` and `about`.

The below snippet should help.

```js
// JS
$(document).ready(function() {  
  // mouse enters .about
  $('.about').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.showsection').slideDown(800);
  });
  
  // mouse leaves .about
  $('.about').on('mouseleave', function() {        
    // if mouse is not hovering over .showsection hide it
    if (!$('.showsection').is(':hover')) {
      $('.showsection').slideToggle(800);
    }
  });
  
  // mouse leaves .showsection
  $('.showsection').on('mouseleave', function() {        
    // if mouse is not hovering over .about hide .showsection
    if (!$('.about').is(':hover')) {
      $('.showsection').slideToggle(800);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS */
.showsection {
  display: none;
  background: #ddd;
}

h1 { margin: 0; }

.about { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=about>
  <h1>About</h1>
</div>

<div class="showsection">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It helped but. When hovering .about section and then going to .showsection. The Section toggles down, toggles up and again toggles down and then sticks.
 It happens when i run the snippet here as well.

Comment: Try using .fadeIn and .fadeOut instead of .slideToggle

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `:hover` attribute will only control the element which it is assigned to, in your case presumable div1. So, you are going to have to use JavaScript.

With JavaScript attach a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event to div1.  Inside those event listener functions, control what you want div2 to do.

That's basically how to do it.